# JavaScript NaN issue with my javascript/jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, nan

Im using javascript to animate some text in line with a div.

textValue can be any number between 14-92. I then need to change this number into a percentage (between 1 and 100) and this animates up from 0 - to the percentage. The problem is that it shows NaN and im not sure what is causing this.

I believe the problem in on the line whileValue = ...

I have declared the variables earlier on in my code.

Any idea what is causing this problem?

Thanks

```
        $("#percent")
            .delay(3000)
            .animate({
                bottom: textValue 
            }, {
            step: function () {
                whileValue = (Math.ceil(parseInt($(".progressbar-cover").css("bottom")-14)/78)*100);
                $("#percent").html(whileValue); //Increase the number to whileValue inline with animating upwards
            }
        });
```

Edit: Added my html for @mike

```
  <div class="progressbar">
      <div style="position:absolute; left:-14px; bottom:0%;" id="percent">0%</div>
      <span class="progressbar-value"><em class="progressbar-cover"></em></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: `.css("bottom")` is not returning a numeric string. Use a debugger and see what string it returns.

Comment: what's the value of `$(".progressbar-cover").css("bottom")` ?

Comment: `parseInt($(".progressbar-cover").css("bottom")` must be returning a string, try `(Math.ceil((parseInt($(".progressbar-cover").css("bottom"))-14)/78)*100)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are doing

```
parseInt($(".progressbar-cover").css("bottom")-14)
```

You may correct by :

```
parseInt($(".progressbar-cover").css("bottom"))-14
```

You will be able to parse "12px", but not "12px" - 14

Comment: You got it. Silly me! Ill accept your answer when the timer finishes

Answer (score 0):

Does `css("bottom")` return a number? or it returns something like:
24px?

Just add:

```
.css("top").replace("px","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alytrem, but since it is a percentage value,

I would go for the follwoing (parseFloat):

```
var value = ((parseFloat($(".progressbar-cover").css(bottom))-14)/78)*100);;
 $("#percent").html(value);
```